# Incremental document ID per group in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a small application that can be used by groups of users, who generate orders. I have a collection name `orders` and inside I have many documents. Each document contains the ID of the user who created it and therefore I know to which group the user belong. Of course, every document has a `ObjectID` auto-generated by mongo.

Every user is part of a group. (I have another collection of `users` and `group`).

This is a brief of how a document inside `orders` look like:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5bb5f9c3f2892eb1748e1574"),
  createdBy: 4
}
```

I want to have on each document inside `orders`, **in addition to the ObjectId**, a non-unique ID that represents the ID/number of the order in relative to that group, so that every group will have an incremental ID for each order that is created.

So **Group A** can have many documents, but if **Group B** creates their first document, it'll show "Document No. 1" everywhere (So I believe we **must** save it to the database)